# Unable to create a field of type Attachement with SQL script in Access database

Tags: ms-access-2010

I'm trying to create a table in an access database.
I've tried the following query but without success:

CREATE TABLE Test ([id] COUNTER (1,1),[AttachedFile] Attachment, [FolderId] Long))

The field of type Attachment seems to be very special. Am'I wrong with the  field type ?

Any ideas ?

Comment: Access SQL `CREATE TABLE` does not support attachment type.

Answer (score 0):

The workaround was to embed the database in Resources